# How to cascade delete only when last FK relation is deleted in Django?

Tags: django

Given a Many-to-many relation in Django:

```
class Agent:
    stuff = chars

class Protegee:
    agents = models.ManyToManyField(Agent, related_name="protegees")
```

I'd like a Cascade behaviour on the Protegee, but only if no more agents are related. I.e. as long as a protegee has at least one Agent, it keeps existing. Is there a built-in for that?

Comment: No, I don't think there's anything built into django to do this.

Comment: Use m2m_changed signal to check if there are agents related and delete Protegee instance if there aren't.